# Using numpy.savetxt while maintaining the shape of the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Using `numpy.savetxt` saves the data as a **continuous line**, how can I preserve the **shape of array**?

**Example:**

```
    arr = np.array([[1,'some',3,4],
                    [5,'wo,dy',7,8],
                    [9,'word',11,12]])

    np.savetxt('example.csv',arr,fmt=('%s'),delimiter='\t')
```

(why tab delimited? - some of the real text has commas in it)

example.csv looks like this:

```
    1   some    -3.0    4   5   wo,dy   -7.0    8   9   word    -11.0   12
```

how can I get it to look like this:

```
    1   some    -3.0    4   
    5   wo,dy   -7.0    8   
    9   word    -11.0   12
```

(so that I can read it into excel or SQL?)

Comment: specify `delimiter=','`.

Comment: makes no difference, as I mentioned the delimiter is only that way because my actual txt has commas and other annoying stuff in it, importing it into excel would go wrong if the delimiter was ','

Comment: ok got it but you should include that in sample.

Comment: Yeah, I guess my question is are we sure this will work for tabs as well even though the file its self looks like one big line, because I have to run this for ~three day and I don't wanna come back to useless data

Comment: I will try and let you know but the question has been marked as duplicate.

Comment: I don't think the 'duplicate' is relevant.  `savetxt` should handle a 2d array without problem.  Tab delimiting is fine, though for testing this I'd prefer ';'.  It shouldn't be producing one line. The mix of strings and numbers is a bit of a nuisance, but the '%s' formating is good start.

Comment: @hpaulj how to remove the duplicate tag because the question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Someone with enough rep can reopen it.  I can't do it from this tablet.

Comment: @hpaulj ok do you have a solution in mind  I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: The example doesn't match the output.  One has int '3', the other '-3.0'.  An important issue is the array `dtype`.  String, object, or structured?

Answer (score 1):

If `arr` really is as shown, `savetxt` shouldn't have problems:

```
In [647]: arr = np.array([[1,'some',3,4],
     ...:                     [5,'wo,dy',7,8],
     ...:                     [9,'word',11,12]])

In [648]: 
In [648]: arr
Out[648]: 
array([['1', 'some', '3', '4'],
       ['5', 'wo,dy', '7', '8'],
       ['9', 'word', '11', '12']], 
      dtype='<U11')

In [650]: np.savetxt('text.txt', arr, fmt='%13s', delimiter=';')

In [651]: cat text.txt
            1;         some;            3;            4
            5;        wo,dy;            7;            8
            9;         word;           11;           12
```

'\t` works fine too.

I don't see how you can get one line unless you either flatten the array first, or specify the `newline` parameter.  Also it wouldn't change the '3' to `-3.0'.

With a mix of strings and numbers the array could also be object dtype or structured.  But as written it is an array of string type.  '%s' is the correct formatter.

Comment: I freaked because I opened the document in notepad and everything was squished into a single line. I foolishly assumed that was how Excel/SQL would see it and my data would be unusable